# What is the correct way to enable soft floating point computation for 68000 with gcc and newlib?

Tags: gcc, 68000, newlib

I am using crosstool-ng to crosscompile for 68000 (version:crosstool-ng-1.24.0-rc2, host OS:Ubuntu 20.04)

My target is a 68000 (plain, not a 68020 or a cpu with floating point support).

I am compiling using a test program which multiplies two floats, using

```
-m68000 -mcpu=68000 -msoft-float -Wall -fno-builtin -O2
```

However, when I execute it, I get illegal instruction error
(notice, this happens only if I use floats)

Suspecting newlib is targeting 68020, I tried adding

```
CT_LIBC_NEWLIB_TARGET_CFLAGS="-m68000 -msoft-float"
```

but that made no difference.
What am I doing wrong? Do I need some code in the illegal instruction handler?

Comment: You'd be better off using the Line 1111 Emulator rather than the illegal instruction handler, as it narrows down the possibilities for you. It's not going to be fast, so keep that in mind.

Comment: @puppydrum64 thanks for your comment. I was however hoping there was a way to have the compiler generate the necessary code.

Comment: Not that I know of, there might be a library somewhere you can import. Don't forget to store its address in your vector table or it won't work!